# Distribute signed integers with a bias in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

Here is a sample code that distributes randomly values of `-1,+1` in an array of size `N`

```
N=100;    
D = sign(rand(1,N)-0.5).*ones(1,N);
```

How can I control the level of bias in the distribution of the numbers?

let's say for example, that only 20% of the array will have `+1`, and the rest `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you make a distribution where 50% (0.5) of the numbers are negative?

```
N=100;    
D = sign(rand(1,N)-0.5).*ones(1,N);
```

---

How can you make a distribution where 20% (0.2) of the numbers are negative?

```
N=100;    
D = sign(rand(1,N)-0.2).*ones(1,N);
```

---

How can you make a distribution where 80% (0.8) of the numbers are negative?

Comment: Should be 

N=100;    
D = sign(rand(1,N)-0.8).*ones(1,N);

Comment: @Metahominid Yes, that is the answer to my last question, not explicitly written, but quite obvious I'd say

Comment: if I run your code I get 80% 1's and 20% -1. He just the opposite.

Comment: @Metahominid Read my last comment again. I gave no answer to my 3rd question, but I made it obvious, as I am not trying to provide code, but teach OP to think. You did indeed guess what the answer would be.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following

```
VAL = [-1 1]   % 2 values
P = .8          % probabbility of selecting first value
Ndraw = 100      % number of draws
R = rand(Ndraw,1) < P 
SEL = VAL(2 - R) % use as index into VAL

    SEL =

  Columns 1 through 19

     1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1

  Columns 20 through 38

    -1     1     1    -1    -1    -1     1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1

  Columns 39 through 57

    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1    -1     1    -1     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1

  Columns 58 through 76

    -1    -1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1     1

  Columns 77 through 95

    -1    -1     1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1    -1     1    -1

  Columns 96 through 100

    -1     1    -1    -1    -1
```